# Extjs4 grid load using URL working with localhost but not with Ip address

Tags: url, datagrid, load, extjs4, localhost

My application grid is loading data using the webservice URL to fill grid with coming data. When Im giving URL like

> function gridSectionResources()
>   {

```
Ext.define('Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['EmployeeID', 'FirstName', 'LastName','Designation','Role','BillingRate','SignedOn','SignedOff']
});
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        //autoSync: true,
        model: 'Person',
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url:'http://localhost:2012/HBWebService/ws/employees',
           // url:'js/Manager/data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'Project'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    });
```

Working fine but
If I'm giving url:'http://172.166.11.9:2012/HBWebService/ws/employees'. It is not working

Answer (score 0):

You must use JsonP proxy for getting data from another domain.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

Comment: Kara   Not another domail....Instead of local host It should work with my own system IP na??

Comment: For browser localhost and 172.166.11.9 is different domains.

Comment: OK In the above example what do to>>Can help in that. I got struck with that

Comment: Replace `type: 'rest',` with `type: 'jsonp',`.

Comment: Kara Can You come into Stack OverFlow chat [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)

Comment: There are two types na..One for rest and one for json

Comment: When Using jsonp It is saying that namespace not declared like that

Comment: Hi It didnt workr=ed for me...Can you tell another solution plz @ozgur Kara

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['EmployeeID', 'FirstName', 'LastName','Designation','Role','BillingRate','SignedOn','SignedOff']
});
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        //autoSync: true,
        model: 'Person',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url:'http://localhost:2012/HBWebService/ws/employees',
           // url:'js/Manager/data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'Project'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    });
```